# Merge unique values in R

Tags: r

Here is sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
data1 <- data.frame(id1=rep(1:5,each=2),nam1=rnorm(5,1))
data2 <- data.frame(id2=rep(3:12,each=2),nam2=rexp(10,1))
```

This merge (and the extention of it as I know it) gives:

```
merge(data1,data2, by.x="id1",by.y="id2")

    id1      nam1      nam2
1    3  2.3152036 2.5419696
2    3  2.3152036 4.8606998
3    3  0.6713674 2.5419696
4    3  0.6713674 4.8606998
5    4  1.4768687 0.6174029
6    4  1.4768687 0.2536772
7    4  2.7471229 0.6174029
8    4  2.7471229 0.2536772
9    5 -0.3507662 2.6098995
10   5 -0.3507662 0.6313073
11   5  2.3152036 2.6098995
12   5  2.3152036 0.6313073
```

So it gives all rows of data1 and also data2! Double rows of the same id.

What I would like to get is this:

```
    id1 nam2        nam2
1    1  0.4395244   NA
2    1  0.7698225   NA
3    2  2.5587083   NA
4    2  1.0705084   NA
5    3  1.1292877   0.31422729
6    3  0.4395244   0.14526680
7    4  0.7698225   2.72623646
8    4  2.5587083   0.02915345
9    5  1.0705084   1.00483006
10   5  1.1292877   0.48021473
```

So I would like to get only the entries of data1 and the correspod. match of data2

Comment: Are you essentially looking for more of a `cbind` than a `merge` perhaps?

Comment: I'm looking `cbind` the column `nam2` from `data2` based on `id`, I cannot just `cbind`, different column length.

Comment: I think the merging fails because your IDs are not unique, so why not beginning by making them unique with e.g. a `make.unique(as.character(data1$id1))`?

Comment: you are right! If you would submit this as an answer I would accept your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @ Vincent Guillemot for his suggestion, solves what I actually needed!

```
set.seed(123)
data1 <- data.frame(id1=rep(1:5,each=2),nam1=rnorm(5,1))
data2 <- data.frame(id2=rep(3:12,each=2),nam2=rexp(10,1))

data1$id1 <- make.unique(as.character(data1$id1))
data2$id2 <- make.unique(as.character(data2$id2))

merge(data1,data2, by.x="id1",by.y="id2",all.x=TRUE)
```