# How to merge two data frames with different dimension keeping the original data

Tags: r

I'd like to merge two data frame that has different dimension of number os records but the same number of columns by column A.

I tried to use full_join or left_join but it doesn't worked I get one data completely messed with number of column E duplicate values like 2.1 two times.

please, someone could help me?

for example:

```
dataframe 1:
 A   B   C     D    E
AG1 10   20    1   2.1
AG2 11   30    2   2.4
AG3 12   40    3   2.5
AG3 13   50    4   2.9
AG4 14   60    5   2.7
AG4 15   80    6   1.9


dataframe 2:
 A    B   C   D    E
AG1  11  90   1   1.7
AG1  13  80   8   1.3
AG3  10  30   9   1.8 
AG3  11  30   10  1.0



I'd like have the dataframe3 like:
 A   B.x   C.x   D.x   E.x    B.y   C.y   D.y    E.y
AG1  10    20     1    2.1    11    90     1     1.7
AG1  NA    NA     NA   NA     13    80     8     1.3
AG2  11    30     2    2.4    NA    NA     NA    NA    
AG3  12    40     3    2.5    10    30     9     1.8 
AG3  13    50     4    2.9    11    30     10    1.0
AG4  14    60     5    2.7    NA    NA     NA     NA
AG4  15    80     6    1.9    NA    NA     NA     NA
```

Comment: If there are duplicate by variables, you may need to make it unique

Comment: @akrun thank you so much, you did guide me for the solution this issue: I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176853/merge-unique-values-in-r

Comment: Of course you get duplications, it depends on the relations between tables (one to many, many to many, which is very bad, one to one etc.). Maybe some further details could be useful for users who want to help you.

Comment: Yes perfectly..